# Why do I have 2 IP addresses for the same computer?

Tags: networking, 12.04

I have a question. So I have a 32-bit Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS set up on one of my computers. I set up a static IP  address for this computer, but now when I go see what devices are using my internet, I notice that my linux server has 2 different IP addresses and both have the same MAC address. I can still ssh into it no problem, but it kind of annoys me seeing two different IP addresses for the same server. Any way to get rid of the other IP address that is not the static IP address that I set up? I don't know if this is important but I have a Netgear WNDR 3700 v3. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Config

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system  
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).    
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.91
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast  192.168.1.255
   gateway 192.168.1.1 

# The primary network interface  
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

my  `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Can you show us your network config(s) ?

Comment: How did you set up an static IP? If you did so the first time you booted the Ubuntu installer then I have no idea how this happened. However if you first booted using DHCP (and thus got an IP in the router list) and later changed to a static IP then the router might be remembering both the new state and the old state.

Comment: How many network interfaces do you have???

Comment: Doug: Same MAC means that the IPs point to the same NIC.

Comment: @Hennes: I booted first DHCP then changed to static.

Comment: @ivan Edit your original question and put the interfaces data there, it'll be easier to format. Use the "<$>" button for preformatted text.

Comment: Bob is right below...

Comment: Please show us the output of any command that actually has the two IPs you're talking about. `ifconfig` from the server perhaps? What makes you think there are two IP addresses here?

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the `interfaces` file in your comments, it looks like you may not have commented out the `auto eth0` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp` lines.  If this is case (can't tell for sure from the formatting) your machine is setting a static IP for that interface first and then getting a second address from your router and assigning it to the same interface.  This is a legitimate and workable setup that shouldn't cause a ton of problems.  However, fixing it is only a matter of commenting out those last two lines.

Comment: Formatting Fixed in Edit... Waiting for Acceptance

Comment: OK after viewing the edit, those last two lines are definitely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Issue:
Got the same issue of having a secondary ip address in eth0 when configuring a static ip address via /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml on home WIFI.

Observation:
ip address cmd show both primary and secondary ip address for eth0,
ifconfig cmd show only 1 ip address on eth0

Fix:
Disable dhcp in /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml -> dhcp4: false

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.170.4/20
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.160.1
      nameservers:
          search: [mshome.net]
          addresses: [127.0.0.53, 8.8.8.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, `auto eth0` just tells the system to bring the interface up automatically on system boot.  the `iface eth0 inet dhcp` would definitely cause it to get a DHCP address to go along with the static IP defined above though.